# R ggplot stat_contour returning an error I can't solve

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I'm working through the Harvard R course on EdEx; I'm up to the Machine Learning module, covering knn. I created a knn fit using the mnist_27 train data and then used the predict function to decide whether the outcome is the digit 2 or 7. Using ggplot, I've plotted the predicted points (y) based on the pixels on the grid (x_1 and x_2); I've then coloured them by y. What I'm now tring to do is place a contour using stat_contour at the p=0.5 boundary. However, I'm getting this error:

> Computation failed in `stat_contour()`: Contour requires single `z` at each combination of `x` and `y`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(dslabs)

data("mnist_27")

knn_fit <- knn3(y ~ ., data = mnist_27$train, k = 5)

x_1 <- mnist_27$train$x_1
x_2 <- mnist_27$train$x_2
y_x <- predict(knn_fit, mnist_27$train, type = "class")
p_hat_knn <- predict(knn_fit, mnist_27$train, type = "prob")
p_x <- p_hat_knn[,2]

knn_df <- data.frame(x_1, x_2, p_x, y_x)

plot_val <- knn_df %>%
  ggplot() +
    geom_point(aes(x = x_1, y = x_2, colour = factor(y_x)), shape=21, size=2, stroke=1) +
    stat_contour(aes(x = x_1, y = x_2, z=p_x), breaks=c(0.5), color="black")

plot(plot_val)
```

The error is telling me that I don't have a prob for the contour for each (x_1, x_2) pair, but my data frame has a p_x for each row, so I'm not sure what is going wrong. If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can't access this dataset. It probably exists in the `dslabs` package. Could you add its `dput` to the question?

Comment: Hi @NelsonGon; yes, the mnist_27 data is in the dslabs package. I used the dput command as requested; here's the Dropbox link to the data:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rkmvjrtuea1sgfb/mnist27data?dl=0

Comment: The reason why I am using the train dataset to generate y(x_1,x_2) is to compare the effect of over-training and under-smoothing to the test set. Once I get this contour thing sorted, I'l repeat on the test set. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand why, but I think that the reason why stat_contour failed was due to insufficient observations for (x_1, x_2), and therefor p.

Instead of using (x_1,x_2) from the train data set (800 observations), I used the full set (mnist$true_p), which has 22500 observations. I recoded to use (mnist$true_p$x_1, mnist$true_p$x_2) to get p_x from the fit. Using the same code, stat_contour then worked.

```
k_val <- 1

knn_fit <- knn3(y ~ ., data = mnist_27$train, k = k_val)
x_1 <- mnist_27$true_p$x_1
x_2 <- mnist_27$true_p$x_2
knn_df <- data.frame(x_1, x_2)
y_x <- predict(knn_fit, knn_df, type = "class")
p_hat_knn <- predict(knn_fit, knn_df, type = "prob")
p_x <- p_hat_knn[,2]
knn_df <- data.frame(x_1, x_2, p_x)
p1 <- ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=mnist_27$train, aes(x = x_1, y = x_2, colour = factor(y)), shape=21, size=2, stroke=1) +
    stat_contour(data=knn_df, aes(x=x_1, y=x_2, z=p_x), breaks=c(0.5), color="black")
plot(p1)

knn_fit <- knn3(y ~ ., data = mnist_27$test, k = k_val)
x_1 <- mnist_27$true_p$x_1
x_2 <- mnist_27$true_p$x_2
knn_df <- data.frame(x_1, x_2)
y_x <- predict(knn_fit, knn_df, type = "class")
p_hat_knn <- predict(knn_fit, knn_df, type = "prob")
p_x <- p_hat_knn[,2]
knn_df <- data.frame(x_1, x_2, p_x)
p2 <- ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=mnist_27$test, aes(x = x_1, y = x_2, colour = factor(y)), shape=21, size=2, stroke=1) +
    stat_contour(data=knn_df, aes(x=x_1, y=x_2, z=p_x), breaks=c(0.5), color="black")
plot(p2)

grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow=1)
```

The code now produces what I need.

[image: Test data set, k=1]

[image: Train data set, k=1]

If anyone has any further suggestions, please let me know. Thanks.